# Dynamically load and databind User control

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Conditions:** I created a classic web site that tracked equipment and I am now converting it to ASP.NET. I have a page that shows information about a specific piece of equipment as well as details specific to the type of equipment I am looking at. An example of equipment types would be Cars, Boats, Plans and bicycles. All of these things have information that is the same such as Manufacturer, Model number, cost, purchase date, etc... but they also have different details that are specific to their type however, some details overlap. For instance both a car and a bicycle have wheels but the boat doesn't. However, a car and a boat have an engine but a bicycle doesn't (if we leave out the human).

When I open the web page for a specific item I want the details for that item type to show and be data bound so that display and edits work correctly. I have found many ways of adding the specific details depending on what type was selected but the only one that allows me to perform a "Data Bind" (similar to a declarative control using <%# Bind("Horsepower") %>) is to create a user control, Register it on the page and either add the user control declaratively or dynamically in a place holder. These methods work, the controls are data bound correctly, will display the data and will allow updates (the user controls are located in a FormView which is data bound to a SqlDataSource).

Each equipment type has it's own details user control so that only the details for that type are shown. In the database the details table has a column for each detail being tracked regardless of type. For instance the details for a car and a boat would both be kept in the details table but the column showing tire size would be left empty for the boat.

My problem occurs when I register the user control for the all the different detail types. Since some details overlap from type to type (i.e. a plane and a car both have wheels) all the controls connect to the SqlDataSource when the page loads (at whatever point data binding takes place) I have code in place that will only allow the correct control to display and looking at the source of the web page no other control even has code on the page, visible or not. Visually everything is perfect and changing types displays the correct user control. However, since all user controls are registered (using the <%@ Register %> directive) they all try to connect to the SqlDataSource which means, I don't know, only the last one to connect is actually connected?

If I only declare/register one control everything works fine. As soon as I add a second control with an overlapping data column name data binding doesn't seem to work or is only for the last control. I deliberately changed the databind to remove overlaps and this allowed all the controls to work but obviously the table columns are not being reused (i.e. cars and bicycles both have wheels so the wheels column would have an entry for both types).

What I need is the ability to show the specific details based on equipment type and have those details databound back to a SqlDataSource for viewing, updates and inserts. I can add the user controls to a placholder no problem but databinding either doesn't happen (at all) or only the last control registered has the correct databinding.

I'm trying to avoid going back to Classic ASP methods. There has to be an 
ASP.NET solution somewhere.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered MVC? Those are the kind of things it is great for with razor, partial views and ajax calls.

Comment: The learning curve and time it would take to convert what I've already done is to great. Besides, there's no guarantee that MVC would solve all the problems. Same with Entity. Both of them also seem to intimate that your database is perfect and everything you need is already there. Who does that?

Comment: Actually the trend is opposite - dealing with objects and behaviors first and letting those flow to the data layer. What you are doing is very much coupled to the database so making things work in an OO way is a challenge, albeit one that can be overcome.

Comment: Steve, Another trick I'm trying is to create a Template Server Control (or Template User Control, whichever will work) to see if I can add the controls that I need at the time that I need them. It seems the only person who has written a way to do this is Scott Mitchell but his example is VERY specific using default data. I'm trying to make it a bit more general than that. Plus, I'm trying to make it work the way a FormView would work where I can establish what template shows based on a "Mode" of course I'll name it something different probably "Type". Any idea on how to do this?